# Apache NiFi PutFTP Processor Cannot Handle Filename with Japanese Characters

Tags: unicode, encoding, ftp, apache-nifi

I'm using PutFTP to send files to FTP server.
But when the filename contains Japanese characters, it becomes unreadable in the FTP server folder.

Original: Japanese_text_漢字テストファイル.csv
After sending: Japanese_text_æ¼¢å­—ãƒ†ã‚¹ãƒˆãƒ•ã‚¡ã‚¤ãƒ«.csv

I have set the property Use **UTF-8 Encoding = true** in the PutFTP processor.

I don't have enough knowledge about character sets. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you upload the file correctly using any commandline/FTP client? If you can, post its log file. And log file of your code too.

Comment: what operation system hosting FTP? what client you are using to look into FTP?

Comment: The base FTP protocol does not support Unicode filenames at all. There are extensions to the FTP protocol to add Unicode support, but both client and server need to support those extensions AND negotiate them to turn them on. Is your PutFTP client doing that? Do you have a log of the raw FTP commands that PutFTP is sending?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a ticket using the [NiFi JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NIFI/issues) or sending an email to the development list. That email I think is dev@nifi.apache.org